# how to get the last value in the non auto incremented id?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using two IDs DM_ID and id. DM_ID is auto incremented while id is not. I want to get the last value of id. 
I used mysqli_insert_id() to get it but i get the last of DM_ID. 
DM_ID and is in one table.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Do you insert it manually? if so - why do you need to select it back? Don't you have it already? What is the scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire a query to get that,

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) from `tbl_name`
```

Or if you need `id` of last inserted record,

```
SELECT `id` from `tbl_name` where `DM_ID` = mysqli_insert_id()
```

Comment: how will assign the result in a variable in php?

Comment: There is not much sense in the second query. If id can be retrieved with this query, it is apparently available already.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
   select id from tablename order by DM_ID desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id from tablename order by DM_ID desc limit 1
```